# How to call a function for each row of a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a function with several paramters. This function returns a data.frame.

I have another data.frame.

Now I would like to call my function for each row of my data.frame (as parameters). The resulting data.frames I would like to rbind.

So I thought something like

```
do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, f))
```

is my friend.

**But:** During this call df gets converted to a matrix. In this process all numbers are converted to characters. So I have to modify my function to reconvert. That's clumsy and I'm afraid I miss something.

So my question is, how can I do this?

As example see the following code:

```
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
# Create data.frame
df <- data.frame(
  a = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  b = c(1, 2, 3),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# My function 
f <- function(x) {
  data.frame(
    x = rep(paste(rep(x[['a']], x[['b']]), collapse=''),x[['b']]),
    y = 2 * x[['b']],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}

apply(df, 1, f)
```

Here I get the error:

```
Error in 2 * x[["b"]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

So I change function f to function g:

```
g <- function(x) {
  data.frame(
    x = rep(paste(rep(x[['a']], as.numeric(x[['b']])), collapse=''), as.numeric(x[['b']])),
    y = 2 * as.numeric(x[['b']]),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}
```

Now I can call

```
 do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, g))
```

and I get

```
    x y
1   a 2
2  bb 4
3  bb 4
4 ccc 6
5 ccc 6
6 ccc 6
```

I tried to use a for-loop.

```
result <- f(df[1,])
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  result <- rbind(result, f(df[i,]))
}
result
```

That does work. But this can't be the R-way. for-loops aren't "R-ish" There's too much what can go wrong. Perhaps df can be empty or does only have one row.

So what's the base-R or dplyr/tidyverse solution?

Comment: I suggest reversing the order of your post -- start with what you _want_ to do (sample input & output), then show us what you've tried. I'm a bit confused after a first read-through.

Comment: Are you aware of `?strrep`? For instance `strrep(df$a,df$b)` is a good starting point.

Comment: note that `apply` almost immediately converts `df` to a `matrix`, so `x[['b']]` is already `character` right away

Comment: @nicola To repeat a string is not the point. That's just an example function. I'd like to call a function for each row of df and rbind the result.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, that's the reason why I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Building on @nicola's comment: `data.frame(x = rep(strrep(df$a, df$b), df$b), y = rep(df$b * 2, df$b))`

Answer (score 7):

Well, `apply()` is meant for matrices and doesn't play with with data.frames. It really should be avoided in cases like these. It's better to write functions that take proper parameters rather than require passing data.frame rows.

```
f <- function(a, b) {
  data.frame(
    x = rep(paste(rep(a, b), collapse=''), b),
    y = 2 * b,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}
```

Then you can use a more conventional `map()` style approach (especially easy if using just two columns)

```
purrr::map2_df(df$a, df$b, f)
```

With more columns, (and column names that match the parameter names), you can use

```
purrr::pmap_df(df, f)
```

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks. I'll try to apply this to my real problem.

Comment: My "real world-function" f has indeed more than two columns. So first I thought I can pass them as "..." parameter. But that doesn't work. So I tried pmap_dfr. But pmap_dfr destroys variables of class Date (https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can do this quite cleanly in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , .(x = rep(paste(rep(a, b), collapse = ''), b), y = 2*b), 
   keyby = seq_len(nrow(df))]
#    seq_len   x y
# 1:       1   a 2
# 2:       2  bb 4
# 3:       2  bb 4
# 4:       3 ccc 6
# 5:       3 ccc 6
# 6:       3 ccc 6
```

The `keyby = seq_len(nrow(df))` part is the clunkiest bit; this in particular is the subject of a few enhancement requests for `data.table`,
 e.g., [#1063](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192632/how-to-call-a-function-for-each-row-of-a-data-frame/48192811#48192811)

Answer (score 2):

## tidyverse answer:

```
> df %>% split(1:nrow(df)) %>% map(f) %>% bind_rows()
    x y
1   a 2
2  bb 4
3  bb 4
4 ccc 6
5 ccc 6
6 ccc 6
```

You can `split` the df by rows (which gives you a list of tibbles), then `map` the function to each row (where the function returns a dataframe), then `bind_rows()` it all back together.

Comment: Nice thought :) Though a bit strange to call it "tidyverse answer" in gigantic text while the provided solution just contains a (rather slow) `for` loop packed into `map()` and a couple of pipes...

Answer (score 0):

No *real* tidyverse answers here yet.

I also think `apply()` is the most sensible function here, but I wrote a function to make it work in `dplyr` verbs, with support for the tidyverse [selection language](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) such as `starts_with()` and `where(...)`:

```r
row_function <- function(fn, ..., data = NULL) {
  if (is.null(data)) {
    data <- dplyr::cur_data()
  } else if (!is.data.frame(data)) {
    stop("'data' must be a data.frame", call. = FALSE)
  }
  if (tryCatch(length(list(...)) > 0, error = function(e) TRUE)) {
    data <- dplyr::select(data, ...)
  } 
  apply(data, 1, fn)
}
```

Demo:

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(max = row_function(max, where(is.numeric)),
         sepal_mean = row_function(mean, starts_with("Sepal"))) %>% 
  head()

#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species max sepal_mean
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.1       4.30
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 4.9       3.95
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 4.7       3.95
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 4.6       3.85
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.0       4.30
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 5.4       4.65
```

---

The actual tidyverse solution is much less convenient, since it requires `rowwise()` and `c_across()`, and transforms the data to a 'rowwised' tibble:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sepal_mean = mean(c_across(starts_with("Sepal"))))

#> # A tibble: 150 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species sepal_mean
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa        4.3 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa        3.95
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa        3.95
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa        3.85
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa        4.3 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa        4.65
```

Comment: Note that you could just do `across(starts_with("Sepal")) %>% apply(1, mean)` in `mutate()` without the need for `rowwise()` or a wrapper function. Also, I believe the OP is asking about how to _not_ treat the row values as a vector (which causes the problematic type coercion in the question), but instead a 1-row data frame.

Comment: Thanks, great addition. Regarding the OPs question, the title is literally "How to call a function for each row of a data.frame?", to which I provided two answers.

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr 1.0 in 2020 there have been a couple of key improvements that make
it much easier to handle workflows like this in the tidyverse. Key points are
`across()` which lets you select columns inside dplyr verbs into a data frame, `summarise()` allowing the result to contain an arbitrary number of rows,
and automatic unpacking of unnamed data.frame results into separate columns in
transforming verbs like `mutate()` and `summarise()`.

With the original setup:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  a = c("a", "b", "c"),
  b = c(1, 2, 3),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

f <- function(x) {
  data.frame(
    x = rep(paste(rep(x[["a"]], x[["b"]]), collapse = ""), x[["b"]]),
    y = 2 * x[["b"]],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}
```

We can now do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(
    f(across())
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   x         y
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         2
#> 2 bb        4
#> 3 bb        4
#> 4 ccc       6
#> 5 ccc       6
#> 6 ccc       6
```

Here `rowwise()` groups the data by each row, `across()` selects all columns,
creating a 1-row data frame, and the data.frame result of `f()` is
automatically unpacked to create many new columns.